# Telegrambot how to send big file with morethan 400 MB

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I'm developing new bot in telegram with [telegram bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

How can I send big file with more than 400MB for my bot users?

My bot and my files in host and I use php for this bot.

Comment: bot can not send big file in telegram api

Comment: we have some bot can do this work in telegram .

Comment: You can't. It's limit